# How to write PL/SQL block to get the addition of the number? Exa. if entering 245 it should process the addition like 2+4+5

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I need to write a block in PL/SQL which may results into the addition of the number inputted.

For example, if I'm entering 245 so it should gives the output like addition if these 3 number(I.e. 2+4+5).

I hope you got my query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey, this looks like a college assignment question. SO encourages you to mention a real-life problem-solving context and mention something you have indeed tried and facing a problem.

Comment: Hint - look at the oracle TO_NUMBER and SUBSTR functions.

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need PL/SQL for that.

```
SQL> set ver off
SQL>
SQL> select sum(dig) result
  2  from (select substr(&&enter_number, level, 1) dig
  3        from dual
  4        connect by level <= length(&&enter_number)
  5       );
Enter value for enter_number: 245

    RESULT
----------
        11
```

It is a simple task to rewrite it to a function:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_dig (par_enter_number in number)
  2    return number
  3  is
  4    retval number;
  5  begin
  6    select sum(dig)
  7      into retval
  8      from (select substr(par_enter_number, level, 1) dig
  9            from dual
 10            connect by level <= length(par_enter_number)
 11           );
 12    return retval;
 13  end;
 14  /

Function created.

SQL> select f_dig(245) result_1,
  2         f_dig(189) result_2,
  3         f_dig(9834188) result_3
  4  from dual;

  RESULT_1   RESULT_2   RESULT_3
---------- ---------- ----------
        11         18         41

SQL>
```

Comment: Littlefoot, Just awesome. Though only 1 upvote is possible, but consider it as 100 from my side.

Comment: 1 last question, Can you suggest me also some Oracle hacks like this or suggest some out of box oracle techniques?

Comment: Huh, that's quite broad, @Ankit. It depends on a particular problem. There might be a hack for something, or might be not. Maybe I don't know it, but someone else does. I don't know whether there's a "list" of those *hacks*, but - if you want, have a look at OraFAQ (here: http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Category:Frequently_Asked_Questions) as you might find something interesting (especially in its SQL part).

Answer (score 0):

You may try below function for the same -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION digit_sum(P_N NUMBER)
RETURN NUMBER
IS
n number := P_N;
s number := 0;
m number := 0;
BEGIN
    WHILE (n > 0) LOOP
        m := MOD(n, 10);
        s := s + m;
        n := TRUNC(n/10);
    END LOOP;
    RETURN (s);
END digit_sum;
/
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=31be1e7b3c55a613ff8e7962a00ba42f) is the fiddle.